# What happens with the induced emf when the time derivative of the area does not exist?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I stumbled upon this thought that I cant seem to resolve. If the geometry of a shape passing through a region of magnetic field is such that just at the point of interest, the derivative of the area with respects to time does not exist, what happens to the induced emf in the loop?

[image]

Take this square wire for example. If it is moving right with some constant speed, what is the emf induced right as the top and bottom vertices reach the magnetic field/ air boundary?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If neither the area, nor the magnetic field vary in time, the is no induction at all. For your simple example, let's start with the induction law for an induced voltage $U_{ind}$ in a square with the field-enclosing area $A$
\begin{align}
U_{ind} = - \frac{d}{dt} \Phi =& -\frac{d}{dt} \int_G \vec{B} d\vec{A} \\
\stackrel{\vec{B}||\vec{A}}{=}& - \frac{d}{dt} (B\cdot A) =- B \frac{d}{dt} A - A \frac{d}{dt} B
\end{align}
I assume, that your magnetic field $B$ is supposed to be constant in time, therefore
\begin{align}
U_{ind} = - B \frac{d}{dt} A \, .
\end{align}
Now if you assume that your square is dragged e.g. to the right (and doesn't leave the field to the right) it doesn't matter how much of its area is actually affected by the field, because $\frac{d}{dt}A$ is zero nonetheless and therefore there will be no induction.

So much for the first question.
The second part is a little bit more complicated.
Let's say the square has a side length $a$ and is rotated in a 45° angle with respect to the $x$-axis (which we set to be directed to the right and coincide with the direction of motion). 
We now want to make use of our formula $U_{ind} = - B \frac{d}{dt} A$ and therefore have to see what happens to $A$, when the square leaves the field.

$x=0$ is set to the place where the end of the field is located.
For every bit of $x$ the square leaves the field, the area shrinks $x^2$. (You can see that by making a sketch of the process.) So in the interval $x\in [0,\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}]$ (half the length of the diagonal), we can state that
\begin{align}
A(x) = A_0 - x^2 = a^2 - x^2 \,.
\end{align}
Assuming that the square is kept at constant speed $v_0$ (it has to be kept at this speed because of Lenz's law), we can write
\begin{align}
x(t) = v_0 \cdot t
\end{align}
and therefore
\begin{align}
A(t) = a^2 - v_0^2 \cdot t^2 \,.
\end{align}
This can be plugged into our little formula and we end up with
\begin{align}
U_{ind} =  B \cdot 2 v_0^2 t \,. 
\end{align}
So the top and bottom vertices hit the air boundary at the time $t_1 = \frac{x_1}{v_0} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}v_0} $ and we plug it in to obtain the induced voltage at this point in time (or space if you want)
\begin{align}
U_{ind}(t_1)=2B v_0^2 \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}v_0} = \sqrt{2}B v_0 a
\end{align}